# Python pywin32 startservice Nonetype object not callable

Tags: python, pywin32

I've been using the pywin32 package's win32service lib to stop and start services for over two years, but for some reason lately the StartServices function I have is producing the "Nonetype object is not callable" runtime error even though nothing has changed, to my knowledge.  I am passing the name of the service as a string in both the StopService and StartService functions.  StopService is working.  StartService is giving the error and it's happening on the function call, not once inside the function.  Can anyone give me some insight into why it's suddenly not working?

```
import win32service

def StartService(serviceName):
  # Get service handles
  hscm = win32service.OpenSCManager(None, None, win32service.SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS)
  hservice = win32service.OpenService(hscm, serviceName,win32service.SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS)
  # Start the service
  win32service.StartService(hservice, None)
  # Close service handles to release memory
  win32service.CloseServiceHandle(hservice)
  win32service.CloseServiceHandle(hscm)

def StopService(serviceName):
  # Get service handles
  hscm = win32service.OpenSCManager(None, None, win32service.SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS)
  hservice = win32service.OpenService(hscm, serviceName,win32service.SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS)
  # Stop the service
  win32service.ControlService(hservice, win32service.SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP)
  # Close service handles to release memory
  win32service.CloseServiceHandle(hservice)
  win32service.CloseServiceHandle(hscm)
```